# write out an array with a promt and for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, switch-statement

I try to click on the button and then a promt will show, inside you write a town in Norway that have population over 100k. if you write correct the town will write out to a UL-list with the name of the town and the population.

I know how to do it with switch case and write every `array` on "case" but I want it to use a for loop.

```
<input id="knappen" type="button" value="legg til byer">

<ul id="output-ul">Klikk på knappen for å legge til byer i Norge med innbyggere over 100 000 innbyggere </ul>


<script>

    var btn = document.getElementById("knappen"); 
    var outputUl = document.getElementById("output-ul"); 

    var byerArray = [
        {name: "oslo", number: 1019513}, 
        {name: "bergen", number: 257087},
        {name: "stavanger", number: 225020}, 
        {name: "trondheim", number: 186364}, 
        {name: "fredrikstad", number: 113622}, 
        {name: "drammen", number: 107930}
    ]; 

    btn.onclick = showTown; 

    function showTown(){

        var by = prompt("Skriv inn en by over 100 000 i befolkining"); 

        for (var i = 0; i < byerArray.length; i++){

        switch(by){
            case by == byerArray.name: 
                outputUl.innerHTML += `<br><br><li>${by} har en befolkning på ${byerArray[i].number}</li>`
                break; 

            default: 
                alert("dette er dessverre ikke en by eller en by over 100 000 i befolkning"); 
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showTown () {
  var by = prompt("Skriv inn en by over 100 000 i befolkining");
  var result = byerArray.filter(byer => by === byer.name);
  if(result.length > 0) {
    outputUl.innerHTML += `<br><br><li>${by} har en befolkning på ${result[0].number}</li>`
  } else {
    alert("dette er dessverre ikke en by eller en by over 100 000 i befolkning"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: you are a legend

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand very well but in case if user write the exact correct name of the town, and you want to show the town name with population.
then u don't need a for loop you can create a dictionary and do it like so

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("knappen");
var outputUl = document.getElementById("output-ul");

var byerArray = {
  oslo: 1019513,
  bergen: 257087,
  stavanger: 225020,
  trondheim: 186364,
  fredrikstad: 113622,
  drammen: 107930
};

function showTown() {
  var by = prompt("Skriv inn en by over 100 000 i befolkining");
  outputUl.innerHTML += `<br><li>${by} : ${byerArray[by]}</li>`;
}

btn.onclick = showTown;
```

working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-pond-l1exn